# Active Storage Uploads to S3 with encryption. How to remove encryption and save file as is in storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

When I upload a file with API multipart to rails server. Rails server uploads the file to s3. But when I go to s3, the file is encrypted which I don't want.

Also when I get the URL from in jbuilder

```
json.url Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(document.doc)
```

the URL I get is of rails path which redirects to S3 image with a key to show the image.

It will be better if I can put the S3 link directly there in the file URL.

Answer (score 1):

The `Active Storage` doesn't store a file with the provided filename instead it uses Rails' `has_secure_token` key.
So even if you try to see the file stored on local (if you're using a deffault `local` service), it'll be saved with some random `alpha-numeric` string.

If you want to explicitly upload with `AWS Server Side Encryption` you might want to update the service config like -

```yaml
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: somebucketname
  upload:
    server_side_encryption: AES-256
```

One possibility you can find if it works by [implementing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/active_storage_overview.html#implementing-support-for-other-cloud-services) a custom `ActiveStorage::Service`. If somebody does it, please share! :D

Or else just go with the `Carrierwave`!!

Ref -

1. [ActiveStorage::Blob](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L41)
2. [ActiveStorage::Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service.rb#L69)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails active storage and don't want to encrypt files by default you need to change `storage.yml` to something like this.

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: somebucketname
  upload:
    server_side_encryption: nil
```

Or if you are using `aws-sdk-s3` gem, here is the link for official guide for [aws-sdk-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingRubySDK.html)

Also you can change existing files encryption from AWS. [Here is the documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-encryption.html)

For URL part you can call `object.images[0].service_url` This will return you something like `https://yourbucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/yr2r6bo1ai1g9yavg7p9480ptdy4?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22images-museum_5_3.png%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27images-museum_5_3.png&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJJWMS7WXXZREOOCQ%2F20200413%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200413T123825Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=14bf4d26d9b3f3c98c29d84c647fc6fa88d903e157a0d41e0ad209937ffaf92b`

You can store first part as object URL. It not changing part of URL.

That part is `https://yourbucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/yr2r6bo1ai1g9yavg7p9480ptdy4`

Comment: Your above code gives error
```
#<Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument: Server Side Encryption with KMS managed key requires HTTP header x-amz-server-side-encryption : aws:kms>"
```
Also local files service cannot go without encryption like paperclip used to do?